# Why did Distributional Q Learning go out of popularity?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, reference-request, deep-rl

I read some papers (for example, [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.06887)) and blogs that spoke about the advantages of distributional Q learning. However, it no longer seems to come up in literature. Did it have any shortcomings that led to its failure? If yes, can someone can talk about it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, distributional RL is a well-studied field in deep RL. Generally speaking, distributional RL needs more computing sources (1.1X), because of the quantile head. We can also find new distributional RL literature in NeurIPS2020 :).

Comment: Hello. Welcome to AI SE. Maybe you can provide 2-3 examples of papers on Distributional RL that were published in NeurIPS 2020.